# Converting SQL to LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have following SQL. I need to convert it to LINQ.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwRptBorrowerAccount]  
AS  
SELECT dbo.tblAccount.[Creditor Registry ID], dbo.tblAccount.[Account No], dbo.tblAccount.[Date Opened], dbo.tblAccount.[Account Status ID],   
               dbo.tblAccount.[Date First Reported], dbo.tblAccount.[Credit Limit], dbo.tblAccount.Balance, dbo.tblAccount.[Minimum Installment], dbo.tblAccount.[Account Type],   
               dbo.tblAccount.Term, dbo.tblAccount.Purpose, dbo.tblAccount.[Account Owner Notes], dbo.tblAccount.[Creditor Notes], dbo.tblAccount.Collateral,   
               dbo.tblAccount.[Collateral Value], dbo.tblAccount.[Legal Status ID], dbo.tblAccount.[Legal Status Date], dbo.tblAccount.LastUpdatedBy,   
               dbo.tblAccount.LastUpdated, dbo.tblAccount.[Unique ID], dbo.tblAccount.[Account Status Date], dbo.tblAccount.Payment, dbo.tblAccount.[Payment Date],   
               dbo.tblAccount.[Balance Date], dbo.tblAccount.[Term Frequency], dbo.tblAccount.[State Change Date],   
               dbo.fn_GetAccountTypeDescription(dbo.tblAccount.[Account Type]) AS [Account Type Description], dbo.tblBusiness.[Business Name] AS CreditorName,   
               dbo.tblBusiness.Address AS CreditorAddress, dbo.tblBusiness.City AS CreditorCity, dbo.tblBusiness.State AS CreditorState,   
               dbo.tblLegalStatus.[Legal Status Description] AS [Legal Status], dbo.tblAccountStatus.[Account Status Description] AS [Account Status],   
               dbo.tblAccountOwner.[Account Owner Registry ID]  
FROM  dbo.tblAccount INNER JOIN  
               dbo.tblAccountOwner ON dbo.tblAccount.[Creditor Registry ID] = dbo.tblAccountOwner.[Creditor Registry ID] AND   
               dbo.tblAccount.[Account No] = dbo.tblAccountOwner.[Account No] INNER JOIN  
               dbo.tblBusiness ON dbo.tblAccount.[Creditor Registry ID] = dbo.tblBusiness.[Registry ID] INNER JOIN  
               dbo.tblAccountStatus ON dbo.tblAccount.[Account Status ID] = dbo.tblAccountStatus.[Account Status ID] INNER JOIN  
               dbo.tblLegalStatus ON dbo.tblAccount.[Legal Status ID] = dbo.tblLegalStatus.[Legal Status ID]  
WHERE (dbo.tblAccount.[Account Type] NOT IN ('CA00', 'CA01', 'CA03', 'CA04', 'CA02', 'PA00', 'PA01', 'PA02', 'PA03', 'PA04'))
```

[EDITED]
and function detail is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [fn_GetAccountTypeDescription]  
(  
 -- Add the parameters for the function here  
 @accountType varchar(max)  
)  
RETURNS varchar(max)  
with schemabinding  
AS  
BEGIN  
 -- Declare the return variable here  
 DECLARE @Result varchar(max)  

 -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here  
 IF EXISTS(SELECT Abbreviation FROM dbo.tblAccountType WHERE [Account Type Code] = @accountType)  
 BEGIN  
  SELECT @Result = Abbreviation FROM dbo.tblAccountType WHERE [Account Type Code] = @accountType  
 END  
 ELSE  
 BEGIN  
  SELECT @Result = @accountType  
 END  

 -- Return the result of the function  
 RETURN @Result  

END
```

Can you please suggest how to convert it to LINQ ? I dont want to use joins.

Comment: I want to use associations. Entities are linked through related properties.

Comment: The awkward bit will be the `fn_GetAccountTypeDescription`

Comment: @Jodrell: I have updated question to show fn_GetAccountTypeDescription

Comment: You could use apps designed to do this sort of thing to get you started like linqpad or linqer... http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: @qes - Agreed! LINQ query for that would be so awkward and will definitely perform slower than having it done in stored procedure and then using LINQ to SQL to call the stored procedure.

Comment: @Mike: I have LINQPAD but it doenst support functions.

Comment: WHY do you want to convert this to LINQ? What objects are you trying to create from this query? If you are just trying to retrieve the results of the query there is no point in using an ORM - actually it's a bad idea to do so. 
LINQ to what by the way? LINQ to SQL? Entities? NHibernate? Each ORM has its own way to specify that some entities should be loaded at the same time instead of loading each entity separately.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: of course it doesn't.  You'll run into that problem anywhere you try to convert this to LINQ, whether that's your app code or LINQPad.

Comment: @Panagiotis : I am using Linq to entities 4.1 code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you will be able to do this without joins, whether using LINQ or not.

Additionally, it seems like quite the exercise in futility.  What benefit do you expect to gain from the time you invest in this?

Furthermore, you haven't specified what LINQ Provider you intend to use, so as is your question is completely unanswerable (each provider has significant differences in syntax).

Comment: I have an application designed in asp.net and I am converting it to MVC3 using LINQ and Entities Framework 4.1 and this is part of that. I dont have data in tables so I cant verify If I am doing it correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, make sure you add tblAccountType to your model and it has an association with tblAccount then do somthing like below.

I'm even less able to test this than you but I would suggest that you have a test database with the same schema and populate it with some dummy data.

```
String[] excludedCodes = new String[]
    {
        "CA00",
        "CA01",
        "CA03",
        "CA04",
        "CA02",
        "PA00",
        "PA01",
        "PA02",
        "PA03",
        "PA04"
    };

var data = context.tblAccount.Where(a => !excludedCodes.Contains(a.AccountType))
    .Select(a => new{
            a.Creditor_Registry_ID,
            a.Account_No,
            a.Date_Opened,
            ...
            Account_Type_Description = a.tblAccountType.Where
                (t => t.Account_Type_Code = a.Account_Type).SingleOrDefault() 
                   ??  a.Account_Type),
            Creditor_Name = a.tblBusiness.Business_Name,
            CreditorAddress = a.tblBusiness.Address,
            ...
            Legal_Status = a.tblLegalStatus.Legal_Status_Description,
            ... etc.
        });
```